# Outlook 2016 can't open attachements

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

Two of my users use win10 1607 and outlook 2016 and they experience problems with opening attachments in outlook:

> outlook fails: We cant open"C:\users\xx\appdata\local\microsoft\windows\Inetcache\content.Outlook\xxxxxxx\ because the user does not have rights to open the temp. folder.

After googling some time I found out that you can manually or by some automatisation clean the temp folder, but some times this incident persists and it's not a solution to do this manually.

Has anybody found a solution to this or what causes this?

Comment: If the user logs in on a different computer, opens and configured Outlook, and then opens the attachment, does it work? It sounds like exactly what the message is telling you: a permissions issue on the temp directory. You could try to sort out their permissions if they have lots of stuff in their profiles, but if not, it might be easier to back up their stuff, delete their profiles, and then recreate them.

Comment: hi musictomyear
thanks for your answer.
the problem is that it happens on a ransom way. if the user opens an attachment and the opens a new mail with a new attachment it may fail and then it maybe fails 10 times in a row until the user closes outlook. when the users starts outlook again everything works fine for a while and then it starts failing again...

Comment: Answers will show up lower down on the page once they start coming in. These are just comments to get more information about the problem.

Comment: Is there sufficient space on the hard drive? Is the user trying to open the same file they had open previously or that is already open?